# Casting C float array to struct of floats and vice-versa?

Tags: c

```
typedef struct cmplx {
    float re;
    float im;
} cmplx_t;
```

Can float array be safely cast to this complex type?

Like so:

```
float s[SIZE*2];

cmplx_t* c = (cmplx_t*) s; // ??
```

What about the vice-versa, struct to float pointer?

```
cmplx_t c[SIZE];

float* c = (float*) c; // ??
```

Comment: Don't do that, your struct is double the size of the float, you can create an array of `cmplx_t`.

Comment: Your C compiler writer is [formally allowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning) to give you a migraine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Original Question

Can an array of `float` be accessed through a `cmplx_t *`?

The language in the C standard appears to permit this. First, we have to consider the conversion of `s`, which is automatically converted to a pointer, to `cmplx_t *`. C 2018 6.3.2.3 7 partially defines the conversion as long as the alignment is correct. The standard does not guarantee that the alignment requirement of a structure is at most the strictest alignment requirement of its members, but this is typical, so the conversion is defined in ordinary C implementations.

Then we have to consider the aliasing rule. C 2018 6.5 7 says:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types:
>
> — a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>
> — a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the effective type of the object,
>
> — an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union), or
>
> — a character type.

Since `c` points to memory that was defined as `float` objects, `float` is “a type compatible with the effective type of the object”, and `*c` is “an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members.” Therefore, `*c`, `c->re`, and `c->im` ought to be accesses permitted by the aliasing rule.

The C standard also does not specify that the layout of `cmplx_t` has the `im` member immediately following the `re` member. C implementations are allowed to insert padding between members and at the end of the structure. However, with members of the same type, there is no reason to do so, and typical C implementations do not. So, in ordinary C implementations, `c->re` and `c->im` should access the desired elements of the `float` array, and so should `c[i].re` and `c[i].im`.

### Added Question

Can an array of `cmplx_t` be accessed through a `float *`.

The C standard does not define the behavior of attempting this. For an object of type `cmplx_t`, `float` is not any of the types listed above.

Comment: Excellent answer as always Eric, but do you also have to consider potential padding between `re` and `im`? Of course, it's not very likely that there's padding here, but I believe it's possible that there's padding and so consideration of it is part of the complete answer.

Comment: @PaulHankin: OP did not even ask if they could use the new pointer to access the array (I just added that into the answer) let alone whether doing so would let them access the `float` data.  But I will add that in too.

Comment: @EricPostpischil What about the vice-versa case (added to question), does the same conclusion apply?